# How to test that a method is called

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have the following:

```
class Foo
  def bar(some_arg)
  end
end
```

It is called as `Foo.new.bar(some_arg)`. How do I test this in rspec? I don't know how to know whether I've created an instance of `Foo` that has called `bar`.

Comment: Can you add some additional detail to the question. As per my answer, this type of mocking is a code/test smell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`receive_message_chain` is considered a smell as it makes it easy to violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

`expect_any_instance_of` is considered a smell in that it is not specific as to which instance of Foo is being called.

As @GavinMiller noted, those practices are generally reserved for legacy code that you do not control.

Here's how to test `Foo.new.bar(arg)` without either:

```
class Baz
  def do_something
    Foo.new.bar('arg')
  end
end

describe Baz do
  subject(:baz) { described_class.new }

  describe '#do_something' do
    let(:foo) { instance_double(Foo, bar: true) }

    before do
      allow(Foo).to receive(:new).and_return(foo)

      baz.do_something
    end

    it 'instantiates a Foo' do
      expect(Foo).to have_received(:new).with(no_args)
    end

    it 'delegates to bar' do
      expect(foo).to have_received(:bar).with('arg')
    end
  end
end
```

Note: I'm hard coding the arg here for simplicity. But, you could just as easily mock it, too. Showing that here would depend on how the arg is instantiated.

**EDIT**

It is important to note that these tests are intimately familiar with the underlying implementation. Therefore, if you change the implementation, the tests will fail. How to fix that issue depends on what exactly the `Baz#do_something` method does.

Let's say `Baz#do_something` actually just looks up a value from `Foo#bar` based on the `arg` and returns it without changing state anywhere. (This is called a Query method.) In that case, our tests should not care about Foo at all, they should only care that the correct value is returned by `Baz#do_something`.

On the other hand, let's say that `Baz#do_something` actually does change state somewhere, but does not return a testable value. (This is called a Command method.) In this case, we need to assert that the correct collaborators were called with the correct parameters. But, we can trust that the unit tests for those other objects will actually test their internals, so we can use mocks as placeholders. (The tests I showed above are of this variety.)

There's a fantastic [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M) on this by Sandi Metz from back in 2013. The specifics of the technologies she mentions have changed. But, the core content of how to test what is 100% relevant today.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion

Comment: This seems like exactly what I am looking for. Can you share if there are any gotchas or is this the recommended way of doing things?

Answer (score 0):

If you're mocking this methods in another class spec (say BazClass), then the mock method would just return an object with the information you are expecting. For example, if you use Foo#bar in this Baz#some_method spec, you can do this:

```
# Baz#some_method
def some_method(some_arg)
  Foo.new.bar(some_arg)
end

#spec for Baz
it "baz#some_method" do
  allow(Foo).to receive_message_chain(:bar).and_return(some_object)
  expect(Baz.new.some_method(args)).to eq(something) 
end
```

otherwise if you want the Foo to actually call the method and run it, then you would just call the method regularly

```
#spec for Baz
it "baz#some_method" do
  result = Baz.new.some_method(args)
  @foo = Foo.new.bar(args)
  expect(result).to eq(@foo) 
end
```

edit:

```
it "Foo to receive :bar" do
  expect(Foo.new).to receive(:bar)
  Baz.new.some_method(args)
end
```

Comment: What if Foo.new.bar does not return anything? I don’t want to mock a return object, only to know that it was called. Note the bar method is tested thoroughly on the Foo spec and I don’t want to repeat tests.

Comment: Maybe something like this? Would need to know additional information

it "Foo to receive :bar" do
  expect(Foo.new).to receive(:bar)
  Baz.new.some_method(args)
end

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use [`expect_any_instance_of`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/working-with-legacy-code/any-instance).

```
expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).with(expect_arg).and_return(expected_result)
```

That said, this method is discouraged since it's complicated, it's a design smell, and it can result in weird behaviour. The suggested usage is for legacy code that you don't have full control over.

---

Speculating on what your code looks like, I'd expect something like this:

```
class Baz
  def do_stuff
    Foo.new.bar(arg)
  end
end

it 'tests Baz but have to use expect_any_instance_of' do
  expect_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:bar).with(expect_arg).and_return(expected_result)
  Baz.do_stuff
  # ...
end
```

If this is the situation you find yourself in, you're best off to raise the class instantiation into a default argument like this:

```
class Baz
  def do_stuff(foo_instance = Foo.new)
    foo_instance.bar(arg)
  end
end
```

That way you can pass in a mock in place of the default instantiation:

```
it 'tests Baz properly now' do
  mock_foo = stub(Foo)
  Baz.do_stuff(mock_foo)

  # ...
end
```

This is known as dependency injection. It's a bit of a [forgotten art in Ruby](https://medium.com/@Bakku1505/introduction-to-dependency-injection-in-ruby-dc238655a278) but if you read up about Java testing patterns you'll find it. The rabbit hole goes pretty deep though once you start going that route and tends to be overkill for Ruby.

Comment: If it’s a design smell, then what’s the correct way?

Comment: @TerenceChow not enough details in your question to give you a better answer.

Comment: Imagine the caller needs foo.new.bar to be called because it’s almost like a transaction. Foo.new.bar has already been tested on its own unit test. So how do I ensure the caller method does this transaction? Easy to test the caller does stuff outside of foo.new.bar but not sure how to test the foo.new.bar is called